# Having Trouble Returning a value from a smart contract, using flask on python anywhere

Tags: python, flask, hosting, pythonanywhere, web3py

I am using flask and web3.eth on pythonanywhere and connecting to a contract, but am having issues returning a value for one of the smart contract functions. No errors are being logged. I have placed several print statements to see where the app is stopping and found that it stops when I call a smart contract function.

Also I should mention that I am able to run this exact code locally without issues.

This is the function that is most likely failing:

```
def getDataFromTokenID(tokenid, contract):
    print('getting uri')
    uri = contract.functions.tokenURI(tokenid).call() # This is where it stops printing
    print('PRINT:',uri)
    html = requests.get(uri)
    name, img_url = html.json()['name'], html.json()['image']
    code = name[-5:]
    return name, img_url, code
```

The function above is called in the following blueprint:

```
@TokenInfo.route('/rarity/<int:tokenid>', methods=['GET'])
def sendTokenInfo(tokenid):

    contract_address = ' ' # left empty for posting purposes
    w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(' ')) # left empty purposefully as well
    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi.abi)

    model = Shape_classifier()
    model.load_state_dict(load(os.getcwd()+'/mysite/app/state_dict.pth'))

    uri = current_app.config['MONGO_URI']
    mongo.init_app(current_app, uri)
    gs = mongo.db.gantomstone_info

    try:
        id_exists = [{"$match": {'_id': tokenid}}, {"$count": "count"}]
        list(gs.aggregate(id_exists))[0]

    except:
        print('getting data from token id')
        name, img_url, serial = getDataFromTokenID(tokenid, contract) ## Stops printing here
        print('opening image')
        img = Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream=True).raw)
        shape = getImageShape(img, model)
        colors = getColors(getCounts(img))
        rgb_count = getCounts(img)
        serialTF = getCodeInfo(serial)
        to_db = {'_id': tokenid, 'name': name, 'img_url': img_url, 'serial': serial,
                 'shape': shape, 'colors': colors, 'serialTF': serialTF, 'rgb_count': rgb_count}
        gs.insert_one(to_db)

    rarity = getRarity(gs, tokenid)
    gs.update_one({'_id': tokenid}, {
                  '$set': {'rarity_values': rarity}}, upsert=True)

    to_json = list(gs.find({'_id': tokenid}))[0]

    return jsonify(to_json)
```

I have tried moving contract address around (both out of TokenInfo view function and into the functions file) to no avail. I have also tried changing the function inputs to receive the get request args instead of the int in the URL, which made no difference either.

Answer (score 0):

If the code uses websockets it won't currently work in web apps on PythonAnywhere.